# Calculating Content Organizer Destination

Tags: powershell

I want to find a way to calculate (using powershell) the final destination of an item in a document library. This little snippet is what I'm trying to do but it keeps saying that it doesn't contain such a method:

```
$List = $Web.Lists[$listname]         
$item = $List.GetItemById($ID)
$FinalDestination = [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRouter]::GetFinalRoutingDestinationFolderUrl($item)
```

I keep getting this error.

> Method invocation failed because
>   [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRouter]
>   doesn't contain a method named 'GetFinalRoutingDestinationFolderUrl'.
>   At line:18 char:120
>   +      $s = [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRouter]::GetFinalRoutingDestinationFolderUrl
>   <<<< ($item)
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetFinalRoutingDestinationFolderUrl:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

What am I doing wrong?  My reading of Microsoft documentation appears to suggest it is a method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$List = $Web.Lists[$listname]
$item = $List.GetItemById($ID)
$edrw = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.EcmDocumentRoutingWeb -ArgumentList $Web
$ecm = $edrw.Router
$FinalDestination = $ecm.GetFinalRoutingDestinationFolderUrl($item)
```